# domain name and connection string to SQL Server when using Python and pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, string, connection, pyodbc

when using Windows authentification with domain name and connection string to SQL Server (using Python34 and pyodbc), I still receive the following error:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SER
N04\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=BRKPNTD',UID='CZMKAJAN04\celocaladmin', PWD='xxxxxx')
pyodbc.Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
Server]Login failed for user 'CZMKAJAN04\\celocaladmin'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I don't know how to get rid of the double backslash, tried raw version of the string, various forms of escaping and nothing helped. Do you know how to solve it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps: `cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SER
N04\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=BRKPNTD;UID=CZMKAJAN04\\celocaladmin;PWD=xxxxxx')` would work better.

Answer (score 2):

Windows authentication for SQL Server connection strings requires the `Trusted_Connection` argument, it can't be specified using `UID` and `PWD`.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERN04\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=BRKPNTD', Trusted_Connection='yes')
```